# Pros & Cons of Running More Than One Node App Instance For A CodeBase

Tags: node.js, express

We can run more than one node app for a code base, all we need to start them on a diff port every time, but i am not sure if doing so is good or not.

I can see the following pros & cons of this approach

Pros:

- multiple domains like sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com and so on, sharing same code base.
- updates code at single place.

  Any other pros you like to mention?

Cons:

- May be it can cause some dead lock on reading some files or some other multi process issue.

  Any other cons you like to mention?

Is it a good move to share code base?

Please share your experience.

Thank You

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do?  For example, forcing people to use a port other than 80 is not expected (so you need some strategy to remap domains to ports), and you probably need some strategy to link a running instance with a different storage server.

Comment: there is need to host a marketing page for a site but still using the code base of backoffice site. so i was thinking to use the same code base for both of domains.

I don't think there be some domain related issue, i can use Nginx as proxy plus for load balancing, so choosing non 80 port is not a issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially spawning several instances of you application which is not a bad or a good thing in itself, it has to do with what you application does. If the application does not access any ressources which will be shared with instances of itself, it is not a problem and you can spawn as many instances as you like, for what ever purpose you see fit.

BUT if your application uses any shared ressources such as a database or flat files, you need to take race conditions and dead locks into account. This is very well handled on ACID compliant databases, on document oriented databases this is not as mature and requires you do have a good grasp on the techniques and languages used.

If there is no obvious reason to run multiple instances of your application, do not do it.

Once you start going down the route of multiple instances, you have to design around bottlenecks, network traffic, backups and a lot of other things that give people headaches, do not do it just because you can.

Comment: You are right, there is no need to share code base between multiple instances. I have dropped idea of doing so. Thank you